# How to convert Teams Conversations(HTML) to JSON in Sharepoint

Tags: html, json, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I am trying to publish a Teams Channel in Sharepoint. By using Power Automate i use the trigger "When new message is sent". But since the Lists in Sharepoint can't take HTML i have to convert the messages HTML into text. The problem is that if the message includes hyperlinks or pictures etc, it really looks aweful on Sharepoint.

Is there a way to get all relevant information from the messeage and display it correctly in the Formatt View in Sharepoint?

Another problem is that i seem not able to use $CreatedDate in the formatting view. It won't show up.

This is the JSON code I currently use for the formatting:

```
    {
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "debugMode": false,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralLight"
    },
    "style": {
      "flex-direction": "row",
      "align-items": "stretch",
      "box-sizing": "border-box",
      "border-width": "1px",
      "border-left-width": "4px",
      "border-style": "solid",
      "margin-bottom": "10px"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "padding": "10px 10px"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "margin-right": "10px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "img",
                "attributes": {
                  "src": "= @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname='+[$From.email]+'&UA=0&size=HR48x48'",
                  "title": "[$From.email]"
                },
                "style": {
                  "border": "1px solid #808080",
                  "border-radius": "50%",
                  "left": "50%",
                  "width": "48px",
                  "height": "48px",
                  "display": "flex"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "box-sizing": "border-box",
          "padding": "0 20px",
          "border-left": "3px solid black"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "flex": " 1 0 300px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {},
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "flex",
                      "flex-direction": "row"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "ms-font-m"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "line-height": "1.5em",
                          "margin": "8px 0",
                          "font-weight": "bold"
                        },
                        "txtContent": "=[$From.title]+', '",
                        "children": []
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "ms-font-m"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "line-height": "1.5em",
                          "margin": "8px 0",
                          "font-weight": "bold"
                        },
                        "txtContent": "=toLocaleString([$DateCreated])"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-font-xxl"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "line-height": "1.5em",
                      "color": "#0077FF",
                      "margin": "8px 0"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$Title]"
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-font-m"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "line-height": "1.5em",
                      "margin": "8px 0"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "inline-block"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "attributes": {
                              "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold"
                            },
                            "style": {
                              "margin-right": "18px"
                            },
                            "txtContent": "[$Message]"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "iconName": "Mail",
                    "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                    "href": "[$DeepLink] + [$ID]"
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "inline-block",
                      "padding": "0 74x"
                    },
                    "class": "sp-field-quickAction",
                    "attributes": {
                      "iconName": "Mail",
                      "target": "_blank",
                      "href": "[$DeepLink]"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the flow seutp I use for trigger and request:
https://mattipaukkonen.com/2019/10/04/low-code-solution-for-publishing-teams-conversations-on-sharepoint/

Comment: I am not sure which html page are you reading but there are many ways to convert html to text but the best way to update the SP with your channel updates is by using graph api's. 
You will get all the information you are looking for using graph api's You can call them in power automate.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT The message itself on Teams can contain HTML, so when some messages are sent with bolds, hyperlinks etc, the message is HTML. Converting it to text is the problem, because it doesnt take into account the links or attached pictures etc. Where do I find these graph api's and where/how do i start? Thanks for answering

Comment: @Thesar:

Could you please go through the document on Graph Api's. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) will help you to quick start.